# MongoDB : Alert when count of records is high

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and have a table like below

```
boxname
time_create
box_data
```

Basically what we are logging here is which box is sending what data and at what time.

Now my requirement is that is to create an alert in system if a box sends more request than a threshold values indicating probably something is wrong or suspicious from that box. I can get the count of records for a box for a time period say 10 mins - but this query is different - each 10 mins check counts for all boxes and check if any exceed more than threshold.

Do I need to do regular polling after 10 mins? Do a program needs to run infinitely to count # and alert - what would be best method to implement the same?

What would be the best mechanism of implementation for such a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem - query scheduler is needed.

That means - every x minutes we need to execute query and check if any box have been matched with threshold criteria.

Scheduler implementation is most based on your current solution architecture (as I am in c# - HangFire will be my selection to implement scheduler).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-scheduler ? But then this NodeJS program has to run infinitely

Comment: that's true - every scheduler (even cron) runs infinitly - btw - you can use cron on  box where mongo is installed to perform a query and raise an email alert